# How to make axis have a top tick

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I add an y axis to a chart and it looks as simple as this one:

[image: Chart]

I want to add a top value tick that will be on the same vertical position as the biggest bar of the chart, now it's blue bar on the very left of the chart. Is there a standard way to set axis option to make it put that cap tick so that not to add it manually?
As an alternative, it can be next step in ticks, so for this chart it can be $700k value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to have a tick at the top, you can use the [nice()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_nice) option of the scale. Example:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 700])
    .range([0, height])
    .nice();
```